# Why do the first two functions not execute once the "/" get request is received?

Tags: express

Individually, I have verified that the two functions in fact work properly. However, they do not execute when the /dashboard route is loaded. Only res.render works and does its task.

I have tried using promises and such but I just keep getting errors and I do not understand them. Do they need to be in the functions themselves or the code I provided?

```
// Display the Dashboard Page and Verify User Profile
router.get("/", (req, res) => {
  verifyUser.checkUserExists;
  verifyUser.loadProfileInfo;
  res.render("dashboard");
});
```

Only res.render("dashboard"); happens and the other two functions dont send anything to my console

Answer (score 1):

You need to call your functions.

```
verifyUser.checkUserExists();
verifyUser.loadProfileInfo();
```

Comment: doing this gives me an error with the "req" variable. console.log(req.user.profile.email) no longer works. i am still an express newbie shall I show you a simple version of the function?

Comment: @Kurnalsaini I guess you need to pass `req` (and `res`) to your functions.